# InvalidCastException in DataView RowFilter

Tags: vb.net

all! Just wanted to start off by saying that I'm new here! :)
I'm also pretty new at coding, so be gentle with me

I'm getting an InvalidCastException error when trying to apply a filter to my DataTable. The thing is, I'm trying to apply 2 filters with one being conditional.
Here's what I have:

```
If cbValue1.Text <> "" Then
    dv.RowFilter = "Value1 " + cbValue1.Text + " " + CStr(nudValue1.Value) AndAlso If(CheckBox1.Checked = True, " AND [Value2] = 'Mon'", "")
End If
```

The error I get says, "Conversion from string "Value1 <= 1500" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

If I have just this part it works just fine:

```
If cbValue1.Text <> "" Then
    dv.RowFilter = "Value1 " + cbValue1.Text + " " + CStr(nudValue1.Value)
End If
```

Can someone show me what's wrong?

Comment: Build your filter sql first and then assign it to the RowFilter. The 'AndAlso If' etc etc is tripping something up.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... I'm not using an SQL database for my DataTable, but a .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [AndAlso Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) incorrectly.  It causes this to be treated as a Boolean expression:

```
"Value1 " + cbValue1.Text + " " + CStr(nudValue1.Value)
```

Try building your RowFilter with multiple lines of code or in a different way, like this:

```
If cbValue1.Text <> "" Then

    Dim strRowFilterExpression As String = "Value1 " & cbValue1.Text & " " & CStr(nudValue1.Value)

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then

        strRowFilterExpression += " AND [Value2] = 'Mon'"

    End If

    dv.RowFilter =  strRowFilterExpression

End If
```

Comment: Aha! Wow, thanks a bunch, I never actually thought of adding to the string like that based on conditions... I haven't tried it yet, but that should work perfectly!! Thanks so much :)